# Lambda including if...elif...else

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply a lambda function to a DataFrame column using if...elif...else within the lambda function.

The df and the code are something like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"one":[1,2,3,4,5],"two":[6,7,8,9,10]})

df["one"].apply(lambda x: x*10 if x<2 elif x<4 x**2 else x+10)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. Is there a way to apply if....elif....else to a lambda?
How can I get the same result with List Comprehension?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Nest `if .. else`s:

```
lambda x: x*10 if x<2 else (x**2 if x<4 else x+10)
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If you mean "not only inside of a `lambda`", then yes, this does work anywhere. In fact, this is the only way I know for making a one-line `if`-`elif`-`else`, except using an `or`/`and` trick.

Comment: @Rightleg the short circuiting might not work here. consider `x==0` - the `or` after `x*10` would slip forward, instead of returning `0`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The fact that `a or b` does not return `True` or `False`, but `a` if it evaluates to `True`, else `b`.

Comment: @Uriel Yep. Anyway, I don't really like this trick, because it can be hard to be sure what will evaluate as `True`, when it comes to very abstract objects.

Answer (score 48):

I do not recommend the use of `apply` here: it should be avoided if there are better alternatives.

For example, if you are performing the following operation on a Series:

```
if cond1:
    exp1
elif cond2:
    exp2
else:
    exp3
```

This is usually a good use case for `np.where` or `np.select`.

---

#### **`numpy.where`**

The `if` `else` chain above can be written using

```
np.where(cond1, exp1, np.where(cond2, exp2, ...))
```

`np.where` allows nesting. With one level of nesting, your problem can be solved with,

```
df['three'] = (
    np.where(
        df['one'] < 2, 
        df['one'] * 10, 
        np.where(df['one'] < 4, df['one'] ** 2, df['one'] + 10))
df

   one  two  three
0    1    6     10
1    2    7      4
2    3    8      9
3    4    9     14
4    5   10     15
```

---

#### **`numpy.select`**

Allows for flexible syntax and is easily extensible. It follows the form,

```
np.select([cond1, cond2, ...], [exp1, exp2, ...])
```

Or, in this case,

```
np.select([cond1, cond2], [exp1, exp2], default=exp3)
```

```
df['three'] = (
    np.select(
        condlist=[df['one'] < 2, df['one'] < 4], 
        choicelist=[df['one'] * 10, df['one'] ** 2], 
        default=df['one'] + 10))
df

   one  two  three
0    1    6     10
1    2    7      4
2    3    8      9
3    4    9     14
4    5   10     15
```

---

#### **`and`/`or` (similar to the `if`/`else`)**

Similar to `if-else`, requires the `lambda`:

```
df['three'] = df["one"].apply(
    lambda x: (x < 2 and x * 10) or (x < 4 and x ** 2) or x + 10) 

df
   one  two  three
0    1    6     10
1    2    7      4
2    3    8      9
3    4    9     14
4    5   10     15
```

---

#### **List Comprehension**

Loopy solution that is *still* faster than `apply`.

```
df['three'] = [x*10 if x<2 else (x**2 if x<4 else x+10) for x in df['one']]
# df['three'] = [
#    (x < 2 and x * 10) or (x < 4 and x ** 2) or x + 10) for x in df['one']
# ]
df
   one  two  three
0    1    6     10
1    2    7      4
2    3    8      9
3    4    9     14
4    5   10     15
```

Comment: thanks for sharing too+1, also I did not get why not `def` a`function` here

Comment: @Wen Lambdas are pretty succinct in general. There's no need to define a function if you use it only once. Lambdas are use and throw.

Comment: ummm, i mean def the if..else funstion and apply it

Comment: @Wen Yep. It _is_ possible, and you _can_ do it. Just that, there's no need to if you don't use it in more than one place.

Comment: Another way of "simulating" the if....elif...else behaviour is calling another lambda function out of the first lambda function like: `df["one"]=df["one"].apply(lambda x: x**2 if x==2 else lambda2(x))                            lambda2= lambda x: x**3 if x==3 else lambda3(x)
lambda3=lambda x: x**4 if x==4 else lambda4(x)
lambda4=lambda x: x**5 if x==5 else x`

Comment: It's indeed elif using np.select, because for condlist = [cond1, cond2, cond3], I quote from the Numpy website, "When multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used"

Comment: what makes these alternatives 'better'?

Answer (score 23):

For readability I prefer to write a function, especially if you are dealing with many conditions. For the original question:

```
def parse_values(x):
    if x < 2:
       return x * 10
    elif x < 4:
       return x ** 2
    else:
       return x + 10

df['one'].apply(parse_values)
```

Comment: I would also prefer an explicit function, especially if your `if-else` chain grows long

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using multiple loc operators. Here is a newly created column labelled 'new' with the conditional calculation applied:

```
df.loc[(df['one'] < 2), 'new'] = df['one'] * 10
df.loc[(df['one'] < 4), 'new'] = df['one'] ** 2
df.loc[(df['one'] >= 4), 'new'] = df['one'] + 10
```