# Populating a new column in a dataframe based on multi-level condititionals

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to populate a column ['Mod_unMod'] based on multiple conditions from other columns in my dataframe (`'cnms_df'`). I wrote some `pseudo-code` to explain the difficulty:

```
IF (cnms_df['CA'] = "NO"):
    IF (cnms_df['I'] ="X" OR cnms_df['I']="V" OR cnms_df['I']="VE" OR cnms_df['I']="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD" OR cnms_df['I']="AREA NOT INCLUDED")
        cnms_df['Mod_unMod'] = "UnMapped"
    ELSE IF (LEFT(cnms_df['STUDY_TYPE].str[:3])="NON")
        cnms_df['Mod_unMod'] ="NON"

    ELSE IF (cnms_df['BJ']="X" OR cnms_df['BJ']="V" OR cnms_df['BJ']="V" OR cnms_df['BJ']="VE" OR cnms_df['BJ']="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD" OR cnms_df['BJ']="AREA NOT INCLUDED")   
        cnms_df['Mod_unMod']
    ELSE IF (LEFT(BK2,3)="NON" 
        cnms_df['Mod_unMod']="UnMod"
    ELSE:
        cnms_df['Mod_unMod']="Modernized")
ELSE:
    cnms_df['Mod_unMod'] = "UnMapped"
```

I have applied simple `np.where` statements, but I am not sure how I could do this with the above levels. Is there a way to do something like this, in a logical fashion?

```
cnms_df['Mod_unMod'] = np.where((cnms_df['CA'] == 'No') & ((cnms_df['I'] ="X") | (cnms_df['I']="V") | (cnms_df['I']="VE") | (cnms_df['I']="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD") | (cnms_df['I']="AREA NOT INCLUDED")), "UnMapped", "Modernized")
```

Comment: You'll need to re-write the logic into a single set of `if...elif...else`, instead of the nesting, but then it's [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991438/lambda-including-if-elif-else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function generating the content of the new column in the
current row as:

```
def fun(row):
    lst = ['X', 'V', 'VE', '0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD', 'AREA NOT INCLUDED']
    if row.CA != 'NO:
        return 'UnMapped'
    elif row.I in lst:
        return 'UnMapped'
    elif row.STUDY_TYPE[0:3] == 'NON':
        return 'NON'
    elif row.BJ in lst:
        return 'Mod_unMod'
    elif row.BK2[0:3] == 'NON':
        return 'UnMod'
    else:
        return 'Modernized'
```

Then apply this function to each row, saving the result in the new column:

```
df['Mod_unMod'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

Comment: Although this is a little more code, I love this approach. It has a logical flow that helps me decipher (I am basically translating spreadsheet functions) the nested conditionals. I had to tweak it a little, but it works great!