# Multiple conditionals in lambda function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to create a new column in my pandas Dataframe by passing multiple conditional statements through a lambda function.

My question is very similar to this one: [Lambda including if...elif...else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991438/lambda-including-if-elif-else)
but the solution doesn't seem to work for my version of python (3.7).

Here's what I have so far:

With one condition, this works:

```
ops['repair_location'] = ops['depot_name'].apply(lambda x: 'Field' if x == 'Field else 'Depot')
```

But I want to add another condition. Using the solution to the linked question:

```
ops['repair_location'] = ops['depot_name'].apply(lambda x: 'Field' if x == 'Field' else (x == 'Unknown Location' 'Unknown Location' else 'Depot'))
```

This returns a syntax error pointing to the last `else` statement.

Comment: What were you intending with this expression: `x == 'Unknown Location' 'Unknown Location'`? In any case, you just have a bare-except, that isn't a complete conditional expression. You really should just use a full function definition, this lambda will quickly become unreadable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use np.where

```
import numpy as np
ops['repair_location'] = (
    ops['depot_name']
    .apply(lambda x: np.where(x=='Field', 'Field', np.where(x=='Unknown Location', 'Unknown Location', 'Depot')))
)
```

Comment: May I know why we do apply here?

Comment: That's what the OP wanted to use and just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

We usually do np.select

```
s1=ops['depot_name']=='Field'
s2=ops['depot_name']=='Unknown Location'
ops['repair_location']=np.select([s1,s2],['Field','Unknown Location'],default='Depot')
```

Comment: The column `depot_name` has values outside of 'Field' and 'Unknown Location'.  This rewrites it and returns an error `ValueError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray`

Comment: @Jacky please try again typo '=='