# How to create new column based on substrings in other column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Substance': ['(NPK) 20/10/6', '(NPK) Guayacan 10/20/30', '46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)', '46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)', '(NPK) DAP Diammonphosphat; 18/46/0'],
    'value': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, .9]
})

    substance               value
0   (NPK) 20/10/6           0.2
1   (NPK) Guayacan 10/20/30 0.4
2   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.6
3   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.8
4   (NPK) DAP Diammonphosphat; 18/46/0          0.9
```

Now I want to create a new column with the short names of substance:

```
test['Short Name'] = test['Substance'].apply(lambda x: 'Urea' if 
                                         any(i in x for i in 'Urea') else '(NPK)')
```

There are two issues with the last line of code. First of all, the output looks like this:

```
    Substance               value   Short Name
0   (NPK) 20/10/6           0.2     (NPK)
1   (NPK) Guayacan 10/20/30 0.4     Urea
2   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.6     Urea
3   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.8     Urea
4   (NPK) DAP Diammonphosphat; 18/46/0          0.9     (NPK)
```

So the second entry was also labeled with Urea although it should be NPK.

Furthermore, my actual data also produces the following error, which I interestingly / annoyingly can't reproduce with the dummy data despite using the original substance names.

```
/var/folders/tf/hzv31v4x42q4_mnw4n8ldhsm0000gn/T/ipykernel_10743/136042259.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Note: Since I have further substances, I will have to add more statements to the if/else loop.

Edit:
The substance names need to be mapped to the following list of short names:

- Urea if *Substance* includes *Urea*
- Calcium ammonium nitrate (CAN) if *Substance* includes *CAN*
- Di-ammonium phosphate (DAP) if *Substance* includes *DAP*
- Other complex NK, NPK fertilizer for all other cases

Expected output for the sample data would be

```
    Substance               value   Short Name
0   (NPK) 20/10/6           0.2     (NPK)
1   (NPK) Guayacan 10/20/30 0.4     (NPK)
2   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.6     Urea
3   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.8     Urea
4   (NPK) DAP Diammonphosphat; 18/46/0          0.9     (NPK)
```

Edit2:
I would then like to add a statement such that I receive the following output:

```
    Substance               value   Short Name
0   (NPK) 20/10/6           0.2     (NPK)
1   (NPK) Guayacan 10/20/30 0.4     (NPK)
2   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.6     Urea
3   46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.8     Urea
4   (NPK) DAP Diammonphosphat; 18/46/0          0.9     DAP
```

Comment: Please edit the question to also include the expected output based on your sample dataframe. Also please clearly state the logic for `Short Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the neatest solution but at least a solution:

```
test['Short Name'] = test['Substance'].apply(lambda x: 'Urea' if 'Urea' in x else 'DAP' if 'DAP' in x else '(NPK)')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['Short Name'] = df['Substance'].str.extract(r'\((.+?)\)')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 Substance  value Short Name
0            (NPK) 20/10/6    0.2        NPK
1  (NPK) Guayacan 10/20/30    0.4        NPK
2     46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.6       Urea
3     46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.8       Urea
4            (NPK) 20/10/6    0.9        NPK
```

Comment: This is indeed a super neat solution but unfortunately my Substance names are a little more messy and Short Names not always included in ( )

Comment: Please show more of your data, then. :)

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
df['Short Name'] = df['Substance'].apply(lambda x: 'Urea' if 'Urea' in x else '(NPK)')
```

```
>>> df
                 Substance  value   Short Name
0            (NPK) 20/10/6    0.2        (NPK)
1  (NPK) Guayacan 10/20/30    0.4        (NPK)
2     46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.6         Urea
3     46%N / O%P2O5 (Urea)    0.8         Urea
4            (NPK) 20/10/6    0.9        (NPK)
```

regex:

```
import re
short = re.compile(r"\W*(urea)\W*", re.I)
df['Short Name'] = df['Substance'].apply(lambda x: 'Urea' if len(short.findall(x.lower())) else '(NPK)')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: could you also include a regex like this?

Comment: You could try to define this pattern: ```short = re.compile(r"\W*(urea)\W*", re.I)``` and replace the statement above by this: ```df['Short Name'] = df['Substance'].apply(lambda x: 'Urea' if len(short.findall(x.lower())) else '(NPK)')```

Comment: That works for the two cases. Any suggestions how to chain that to the 4 cases I actually need?

Comment: I suggest that if you have more than one substance you could store them in a list like this: ```short_substances = [Urea, NPK, Subs1, Subs2]```, then iterate over this list calling the search regex ```apply(lambda x: substance [pattern.findall(x.lower()) for substance in short_substances]```, but for that you would have to pass the variable of each iteration of the list ```short_substances``` to the pattern, by this way: ```rx = r'\b(?<=\w){0}\b(?!\w)'.format(short_substance)```

Comment: The difficulty is that I really need the else case as default. Only three of the substance names can be easily matched, everything else needs to go on 'NPK'. The best I can come up with is
`test['Short Name'] = test['Substance'].apply(lambda x: 'Urea' if 'Urea' in x 
                                             else 'DAP' if 'DAP' in x else '(NPK)')`

Comment: I would recomment to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991438/lambda-including-if-elif-else), also using  ```lambda``` *functions* you could implement *conditional* statements, by this way: ```lambda x : 'Urea' if 'Urea' in x else ('DAP' if 'DAP' in x else '(NPK)')```