# Use Values in column as String Slicer of another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm trying to use a cell value as the slice for a string in a new column. For example, if I create this table.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name':['This is a title'], 'Number':[-5]})

               Name Number
0   This is a title     -5
```

And create a new column like so:

```
data['Test'] = data.Name.str[:data.Number.item()]
```

It'll create the new column, as expected:

```
               Name Number       Test
0   This is a title     -5  This is a
```

The issue occurs when I have more than row, so if I create the following table:

```
 data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name':['This is a title', 'This is another title'], 'Number':[-5, -13]})

                     Name   Number
0   This is a title             -5
1   This is another title      -13
```

The creation of the 'Test' column yields:

```
can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

I understand why this is happening since the column now has more than one value, what I want to know is how can I do this with a dataframe that has more than one row? I've tried .items(), .values(), etc. and the new column just becomes NaN.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `axis=1` and move on `dataframe` row by row.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name':['This is a title', 'This is another title'], 'Number':[-5, -13]})

data['Test'] = data.apply(lambda row: row['Name'][:row['Number']], axis=1)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
                    Name  Number        Test
0        This is a title      -5  This is a 
1  This is another title     -13    This is
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out how to lambda it, obviously couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @bobby_pine, welcome. with apply(lambda row: ..., axis=1), we move row-wise and in each iteration, we get a row and we can get value on each column by name of the column and do what we like. you can see these two answers for different use of [`axis=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52854800/1740577) and [`axis=0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317839/1740577) on `apply`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, here, you need to loop. A list comprehension will be the most efficient:

```
data['Test'] = [s[:i] for s,i in zip(data['Name'], data['Number'])]
```

output:

```
                    Name  Number        Test
0        This is a title      -5  This is a 
1  This is another title     -13    This is
```