# Some trouble with Python's lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I am currently making a NN by hand as personal project.  I have definded many activation functions by using lambda which I pass into another method.  So I need it to be a lambda.  I am trying to make one that is a 3 piece, piece wise function.

```
z = 0 where x <= 0
z = x where 0<x<1
z = 1 where 1 < x
```

The trouble is that python's lambda seems to only let you use one if and one else condition in it.    Is there anyway around this?

This obviously doesn't work because it doesn't do what I want it to do

`lambda x : 0 if x<0 else 1`

This doesn't work becasue elif isn't defined so its invalid syntax.

`lambda x : 0 if x<0  x elif 0<x<1< else 1`

Comment: `0 if x<0 else x if 0<x<1 else 1`

Comment: I'd recommend just writing out the if statements, though. Clarity trumps cleverness.

Comment: Another approach: `lambda x: min(max(0,x), 1)`

Comment: Did you know that you can just define a function normally with a `def` statement and then pass it by name?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I actually did not.  Thanks all of these are good answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lambda including if...elif...else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991438/lambda-including-if-elif-else)

Comment: @mkrieger1.  I think some of those answers are good but I thought the answers here were more useful (and more general because that one is focused on pandas specific functions)

Answer (score 0):

Embed the if in the else:

```
lambda x: 0 if x<=0 else (x if x<1 else 1)
```